# Joomla site view without "read more"

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-component

I am new to Joomla and tried to make a little component on my own. 
I redirect the user on the site to a view where he can insert some information in a form and submit them.
The logic somewhat works, but Jommla inserts three links for posts, read more and another one. How can I prevent Joomla from adding this?

My code for the view:

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

JHtml::_('behavior.framework');
JHtml::stylesheet('my-file.css', 'components/com_component/');

echo '<h1>Form</h1>';
?>

<form action="<?php /* Create JRoute*/ ?>" method="post" name="mailForm">

   <ul>
    <?php foreach($this->form->getFieldset() as $field): 
    if ($field->label!="") {
        echo '<li>'.$field->label.$field->input.'<br/></li>';
    } else {
            echo '<li>'.$field->input.'</li>';             
    }?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Senden!">
            <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
    </div>
</form>
```

The rendered result (not intended links marked red):
[image]

Comment: Can you add the rendered html source with the links that are added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the XML declaration of the JForm form update the entry for editor:

```
<field name="description" label="Bescheibung" type="editor" />
```

add additional attribute:

```
 buttons="false"
```

Reference:
http://docs.joomla.org/Editor_form_field_type